# How to deploy django with Kubernetes on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a web app with the following stack: Django + MySQL + Celery + Redis.

Do you know some good explanation about how to deploy this stack on Amazon with Kubernetes.

I'm looking for some guidance covering the following topics:

1.) Creating containers for the components from my stack

2.) Explaining what can be a persistent solution for MySQL in the containers world (maybe http://vitess.io/?)

3.) Creating Kubernetes cluster on AWS

4.) Configure Kubernetes / handle network

5.) Deploy

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question to expect a complete answer, but I can try to touch a couple things.

Kubernetes should already work on AWS, so simply running `kube-up.sh` should work.  This includes the network.

Kube on AWS has support for EBS volumes, so you can store your MySQL data there.

Creating containers for your components - I would start by looking at the Docker library for useful base images.